# How many different arrangements are possible if $3$ letters are randomly selected from the word CHALLENGE and arranged into ‘words’?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many different arrangements are possible if $3$ letters are randomly selected from the word CHALLENGE and arranged into ‘words’?

$$\frac{9P3}{2! \cdot 2!} = 126$$

but the answer is $246$.

Comment: Your calculation gives the number of distinguishable arrangements of all of the letters in the word CHALLENGE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the words with all different letters: select from CHALENG:
$${7\choose 3}\cdot 3!=210.$$
Consider the words with two letters L: select from CHAENG:
$${6\choose 1}{3\choose 1}=18.$$
Consider the words with two letters E: select from CHALNG:
$${6\choose 1}{3\choose 1}=18.$$
Add up to get $246$.

Comment: I understand the first case where there are three different letters but not the other two. Why is it 6C1 x 3C1

Comment: first you select one letter out of 6 available CHAENG. So, now you have three letters, two of them are the same, for example: CLL. There are 3 words you can make by placing C in any of 3 positions. Also, you can multiply by $3!/2!=P(3,1)={3\choose 1}$.

Comment: okay thank you for your support

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The given word is
$$CHALLENGE $$
we can write it as $$CHALLEENG$$
where there are total 9 words and 7 distinct words

We can think of this problem as- there are 9 balls in a box A out of which there are 7 balls of different colur and two balls which share the same colour out of 7 balls.
{R,B,G,Y,V,I,O,R,G}.Now in how many ways can we take out 3 balls and keep it in another box B ?

**CASE $1$**

We can keep balls of all different colours in the box B.

.ie 
$$7P3$$
$${7\choose 3}\cdot 3!=210 ways.$$

**CASE $2$**

Say box B has 3 different holes in which 3 balls can be kept

We can keep 2 balls of same colour different colours in two holes and in the 3rd hole we can keep 6 different balls.

Therefore in the third hole 6 different balls can be kept.which can we again be done in three places

.ie 
$$6*3$$
$$=18 ways.$$

Now case two repeates itself of the ball of another colour therefore again 18 ways

therefore total number of ways of doing so-$$18+18+210=246ways.$$

PS-I know that the solution to the problem was already given ,but i thought of doing it in another way.